# Update local gem source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm testing a gem in a Rails project.

The current Gemfile:

```
gem 'mygemname', path: '/path/to/my/gem'
```

When I edit a gem locally I can build the gem, remove the gem from `Gemfile`, run `bundle install`, add the gem back to the Gemfile and run `bundle install` again. Is there an easier way to do this locally?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use `bundle config local.GEM_NAME /path/to/local/git/repository` from the command line then every time you reload your application it will load the latest source from your file system.

To remove the changes (when you have pushed your code to GitHub or RubyGems), you need to run `bundle config --delete local.GEM_NAME`

Source: http://bundler.io/v1.10/git.html

Answer (score 5):

You can bump your Gem's version. Next time you run `bundle` your gem will be updated to the next iteration.

```
VERSION = "1.0.0"
```

Bump the patch version to

```
VERSION = "1.0.1"
```

Now just run `bundle`. Bundler will notice it and log `1.0.1 (was 1.0.0)` in the output.