# How can I have bundler reload a changing local gem under development?

Tags: rubygems, bundler, gemfile

It has the same version. I'm just starting, so it's not worthwhile to change the version yet. I suspect `bundle update` doesn't reload a gem of the same version and doesn't reflect the (minor minor) changes. I also suspect `gem build` and `gem install` in the directory of the `gemspec` doesn't do the trick. Or - it's just my code that is still wrong.

I have the gem loaded through the Gemfile with

```
# Gemfile
path '/path/to/gem_development' do
    gem 'acts_as_developing_gem'
end
```

Here ([Update local gem source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427400/update-local-gem-source-code)) is a solution when you added your local gem through `bundle config local` but doing that obviously requires a remote git repository corresponding to your local one. Hence the solution proposed will not work for me.

Without remote git repository the only remaining choice is the `gem 'uber-gem', path: "/local/gems/development/path"` or the one that I chose.

Also nothing changes when I restart the `rails console`

Yours sincerely